Gamobject boxCollider Not registering my Player Tag
I have been working on this small 3rd person open world type project. I implemented such that when my player enters a pickable items box collider (is triggered) I will be able to interact with it. I created a player tag to the movable player and a script attached to the item.
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = true;

        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }

However, whenever I enter the box collider of the item with my player it does not register playerInRange, why? Here is the inspector of my player:

Initially it worked, as I used a static camera following the player, but I decided to change to cinemachine camera, changing the player movement a bit (But i cant imagine that it matters as the item box collider is only searching for an object with the player tag?).
Also the player object has a rigid body, maybe this can be a problem? I'm not sure, I'm somewhat of a beginner.
Here is a pic of my old player inspector:


SOLVED!
I chnaged the collider from capsule collider to box collider. I have no idea why, but it worked.
Ford the solution here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/box-collider-not-detecting-collisions.196932/

What Unity version are you using, out of curiosity?

Are you sure it was not maybe just not configured to be isTrigger?
